# SKLearn/Python - How to sample dataset according to a certain distribution?

Tags: distributions, python, sampling, scikit-learn

I have a set of training data and a set of test data. The test data itself is similar to the training data, however, it has a different distribution on its own than the whole training set.

I'd like to learn the distribution of the test set, and generate a new training set from the initial training set but with the same distribution as the test set.

How can this be done? I did some google/SO research, but most of what I've found was about learning a distribution but then generating random data, however, I'd like to just select a subset of my existing training data that has the same distribution as the test set. How can this be done with Python (SKLearn, Pandas)?

Comment: This is a flawed approach. The idea of test data is to see how your model might perform in data it hasn’t seen, the way that Siri is expected to perform on speech samples of people who have yet to speak their first words. Pretend the test data set doesn’t exist until you go to test.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't work in this case because the test set's properties are so different than the training set's (while it's still the same problem). Even if we use the same scaling/pca/whatnot than we used on the training set.